# What is issue? Yii2 elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2

## Model

```
Class User extends yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord{
    public function attributes(){
        return ['name','role'];
    }
}
```

## Action

```
$user = new User(['name' => 'my name', 'role' => 2]);
if ($user->save()) {
    var_dump(User::findOne(['role' => 2]));
}
```

result output:
`NULL`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Could be a problem related to the User validate

try using

```
$user = new User(['name' => 'my name', 'role' => 2]);
if ($user->save(false)) {
   var_dump(User::findOne(['role' => 2]));
}
```

if the user is saved you must control the validation rules for User.

Comment: I not have an validate only saving. I have try your script not work browser return "null". it mean model was saved and var_dump execute

Comment: This can't be the problem - `var_dump` is firing, so `save` must be returning `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `User` model does not have the necessary validation rules. In other words, `new User(['name' => 'my name', 'role' => 2])` produces the same result as `new User()`.

Do you have rules for `name` and `role`? Because if you don't, these attributes will not be set:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name', 'role'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

Actually, for testing try initializing your model manually:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'my name'
$user->role = 2;
if ($user->save()) {
    var_dump(User::findOne(['role' => 2]));
} else {
    echo 'Validation failed';
}
```